# trace the exact source of an error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to trace an error in an angularjs application which is :

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module minovateApp due to:
Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($mdIconProvider ) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

Obviously there is nothing related to that error in the 68th line in `angular.js`.

How can I trace the exact source of the error in an angularjs application ?

Comment: Debugging in angular is a problem.

Comment: Often times you can debug the issue without knowing the exact source of the error by simply focusing on the error message itself.  Case in point your error that is related to dependency injection.  You should be able to resolve it without having an exact line number.

Comment: @jbrown I only see this error when I use `ng-strict-di` because I want to minify my application and it will fail to invoke functions which do not use explicit function annotation, so I need a useful debugging info to assist trucking down the root of this error.

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU - your error is related to $mdIconProvider which is part of angular-material.  Did you include the angular-material script in your app?

Comment: @jbrown yes ofcourse I did otherwise all my angular-material components wont even work, isn't it by chance that angular-material doesn't use annotation ?

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU - by saying "yes of course I did..." you are implying that I should have known that your angular-material components were working.  How would I know that?  I was just trying to walk you through resolving your issue with otherwise very limited information from you.  I wish you well in resolving your problem.

Comment: @jbrown thanks for your time, I didn't want to include my index file and app.js file because they have more than 3K lines, and thanks for helping me resolving the error but this wasn't the only error I'm getting from angular-material when I use `ng-strict-di` I only want to know how I can trace the root of that error since the error in console doesn't help with anything